# calc() not working with transform in Internet Explorer/Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, css-transforms, css-calc

I am trying to scale a div by an amount equal to 1/2.9. I can type it as a decimal, but it won't be as accurate as the fraction.

This code works in both IE and Chrome:

```css
.container {
  position:    absolute;
  width:       200px;
  height:      290px;
  transform:   scale(0.3448275862068966);
  background:  #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

However, with `calc()`, it only works in Chrome:

```css
.container {
  position:    absolute;
  width:       200px;
  height:      290px;
  transform:   scale(calc(1/2.9));
  background:  #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

IE just ignores my `calc(1/2.9)`. It does not scale the container.

Is there anything I can do to make IE correctly render `calc()`?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/104773/

Comment: No. Maybe in 2034, live with it. Two choices: complicate your code for everyone just for ie users (mostly: workplaces and grandma pc) or don't use css transformation at all.

Comment: Some wiseman once told me: "Support IE and be doomed." Actually that was me...

Comment: @Temani Afif, this isn't a solution. I am building a website. Some of my visitors will be IE users.

Comment: This is a potential solution for anyone that will see this question ;) and believe this is the ONLY solution ... but if you still want to force IE to understand things, good luck :) but don't waste a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since you're not even performing arithmetic with dynamic values here, just do yourself a favor and hardcode the ratio to three decimal places. Three decimal places is all the precision you need, even when taking high-resolution device displays into account.